# XSLT 1.0 Regular Expression in for loop

Tags: regex, xslt

So I have xml like

```
<depot id="D7">
    <address> 
        <number>6000</number> 
        <street>Yonge</street> 
        <city>Toronto</city> 
        <province>ON</province> 
        <postal_code>M2M 2E4</postal_code> 
    </address> 
</depot>
```

I have hundreds of there depot in xml

now in my xsl, I have defined a variable called 'locale' that stores a postal code like "M1C".
After this I want to select only those depot where the postal_code is like 'locale'. In other words, If I specify locale to be "M1C", then I should get all the depot whose postal_code contains "M1C", so depot with "M1C A18", "M1C B2C", etc all should be in the result.

Currently I have the line below

```
< xsl:for-each select="depot[address[postal_code=$locale]]">
```

which gives me only depot with exact postal code match and not the ones with "M1C A18", "M1C B2C", etc. I want to use something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="depot[address[postal_code=*$locale*]]">
```

with wildcards but it does not works. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
depot[starts-with(address/postal_code, $locale)]
```

Here we assume that any `depot` has a single `address/postal_code` descendent and that no possible value of `$locale` is a prefix of any other possible value of `$locale`.

**If, for example, the second assumption isn't true, then use**:

```
depot[starts-with(address/postal_code, concat($locale, ' '))]
```

True regular expression capabilities are available in XPath 2.0 (such as the `matches()` function), but they aren't necessary for a simple problem as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="depot[contains(address/postal_code,$locale)]" />
```

to match only `depot` elements that contain the fragment defined in `$locale`.